# How to get back to the previous CCScene?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I have one CCScene, in which their is About us ICON. When I tap on it, goes to the next CCScene where the information to display.

**Now, what happen**

When I touch on the back option of the android phone, Game closed.

**what I need**

when I click the back, It takes me to the First CCscene, where the Icon of ABOUT us present.

**What should I do for this ???**

**Solution : From what I solve**

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().popScene();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CCDirector` to push scenes on top of **running** scenes.
Say you have `scene1` and `scene2` both instances of `CCScene` (or a subclass of `CCScene`) then when the user taps the about icon :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:scene2]; // Assuming scene1 is already running
```

when the user taps the back button :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
```

**EDIT :** According to your comment (and in java this time :)) :

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
   super.onBackPressed(); 
   if(backPressFlag==1) { 
       CCDirector.sharedDirector().popScene();
   } 
}
```

And of course this will work only if you pushed the About scene with :

```
  CCDirector.sharedDirector().pushScene(AboutScene.scene());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I got your point but the point is, I have an android phone and on the back button of android. I need to handle this thing. If I cant figure out this then probably I'll choose this solution.

Comment: oh you removed the iphone tag :). Can't you do it in the method handling the back button ?. Regardless of the input you should be able to use this. Just use a context telling you in what page you are in your application and use the above when you are in the about page

Comment: I create a flag  on every Scene and when the back button called. I applied the condition for handle the flag. condition always gives me right value but can't call the CCScene. It just throw me out the Application

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  if(backPressFlag==1){
      CCScene scene = MainScene.scene();
      CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
  }
 }

Comment: So if you replace this code with the push/pop code it should work. I edited my answer. check it out

Comment: can you post in your original question (via edit) the code where you create you main scene and handle the about icon button ?

Comment: Well it looks fine. Unfortunately I come from the iOS world and maybe the problem is not with the scene but with the handling of the back button events. Did you try to debug your code ? in what line does it crash ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way on clicking back button

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().getRunningScene().removeAllChildren(true);
```

Now create new scene

```
    sceneIndex--;
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(backAction());
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(scene);
```

Here backAction() is same as in cocos examples

Comment: it's like.. I have a CCscene in which a single icon is present .. when I tap on it, take to the another CCscene And now I pressed back button which is the part of phone that time I want to show first ccscene... but in my case : activity closed

Comment: I have update the code, now you can give me some suggestion for complete this thing

Comment: create enum class and assign a varible each  to the scene.When you press back then compare that enum variable and respond according to the scene.  Ex: if(scene.mainSceme == enum.mainscene){ do ur task}

Comment: in the onBackPressed method , I'll check this or somewhere else

Comment: in onBackPressed method only